# Adjust the brightness of the screen through code

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, screen-brightness

I am developing an iPhone application and I need to adjust the brightness of the screen through my application, in the same way as we do through the Settings app.

I have searched but have not found a solution.

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

But only on iOS 5. Not supported on earlier iOS versions.

Comment: then how to implement this in ios 4,Can you give any idea please...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you require compatibility with older iOS versions, try a black overlay on top of your application's main window with partial alpha. I used it in an iPad app - only downside is that it won't darken elements like popovers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `brightness` property of [`UIScreen`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html).  This is a new API in iOS 5.  You can't do it in older versions.