# iOS - Change the screen color temperature

Tags: ios

I want to build an iOs app like f.lux.
It changes the screen brightness of device based on daytime.
I know I have to jailbreak my device. But I don't know how to implement this app.

Please suggest me any useful API to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do can't be done in an approved App Store app.

Comment: Is the purpose of your app simply to dim the screen for _any_ running application? If so, that is something best left to the system itself, see my answer below.

Comment: Just an FYI, F.lux doesn't change brightness, it changes the display temperature (increases/decreases the blue levels)

Answer (score 1):

iOS already has that system-wide feature built-in: see **Settings > Brightness & Wallpaper**, under **Auto-Brightness**:

[image: auto brightness]

Although it is possible to programmatically control the device's brightness, there is not a public API for determining the outside light, so this is functionality that the OS handles.

Comment: he said programmatically

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that this functionality is already present in the operating system itself and an app is not needed to accomplish it.

Comment: Volume control is also provided by the device, still there are some cases when you might want to change the volume programmatically

Comment: And to echo @rmaddy's comment, being able to set the brightness still doesn't allow one to know the ambient light outside the device and set it accordingly. So this is something best left to the system to handle.

Comment: @Stuart is right, I upvoted his answer.

Comment: Doesn't auto-brightness work based on ambient light levels, NOT time of day as requested in the question?

Comment: The question has since been edited, it originally asked about changing based on outside brightness

Answer (score -1):

Try this (iOS5 and greater only):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:1.0];
```

From related question: [Adjust the brightness of the screen through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894232/adjust-the-brightness-of-the-screen-through-code)

Comment: This will not allow an app in the background to adjust the device's screen brightness based on outside light sources.

Comment: Ah, that's right. The device already does it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Go through the **brightness** property of **UIScreen** which is a new API available after IOS5.

Comment: This is equivalent to @AnthonyC's answer, right? And in any case, it still does not address the problem of reading the outside brightness (via the ambient light sensor).